# Bookwork Preparation for Exams

Tags: education

Has anyone got advice for learning bookwork. I have one particular module which is absolutely full of it. Currently I keep looking at it over and over but 'the tricks' aren't sticking.

Comment: I assume by bookwork you mean memorising proofs? The best advice I can give is to write out the proofs for yourself repeatedly without looking at your notes. If you get stuck, check your notes to see what the next immediate step is and then try and finish the proof by yourself. Wash, rinse and repeat.

Comment: I agree with Tom, but I like to try talking through the proof as if I'm teaching someone.